# Xamarin.Forms Calendar

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, view, xamarin.forms

I am trying to display a calendar view in my Xamarin.Forms Application (MVVM). I have the function that does so, it is defined in a ViewModel class called "Calendar_vm.cs". It is defined as below:

```
public Calendar_vm(string email, string password)
{
            Email = email;
            Password = password;

            this._user_profiles = new UserProfile_vm(Email, Password);

            SfCalendar calendar = new SfCalendar();
            List<DateTime> black_dates = new List<DateTime>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                DateTime date = new DateTime(2018, 4, 1 + i);
                black_dates.Add(date);
            }

            calendar.BlackoutDates = black_dates;


            this.Content = calendar;
}
```

Well the problem here is that obviously i get this error on the last line (`this.Content`):

```
'Calendar_vm' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'Calendar_vm' could be found ...
```

I know why i get this error, because i don't have direct access to the View (Because of the MVVM model).

Is there an alternative to this line ?

*Note - i dont want to do this in Xaml, only .cs

Comment: you need to create your calendar inside your view (contentpage) and not inside your viewmodel

Comment: I know how to get it working by doing so, but i need to put it inside my viewmodel, as i am making this calender exclusive to the signed in users and would be writing code to manipulate the calendar from there.

Comment: you need to separate your concerns.  Manipulate users information from your viewmodel, use bindings (or use messaging to send information to your view which needs to hold the calendar).  Viewmodel is not the place where your maniupulate graphical controls.